# R gtsummary package: How to Hide Colums in Summary Table

Tags: gtsummary

I'm using gtsummary to prepare my tables, I'm trying to hide one of the columns from the groups, the third column labeled as "1, N = 61"

Below is the code ran,

```
library(gtsummary)
trial <- trial
trial %>% 
tbl_summary(by=response,
            statistic = list(trt~"{n}/{N} ({p}%)")) %>% 
  add_overall() %>%
  add_p() %>% 
  modify_column_hide(columns = "1")
```

[The output provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otX6B.png)

I was expecting that the third column would be hidden "1, N = 61"

Comment: No need to post your question to multiple forums please https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1392

Answer (score 0):

The 2 columns (0 , 1) are named "stat_1" and "stat_2" respectively.

So, to hide the one you ask for:

```
trial %>% 
  tbl_summary(by=response,
              statistic = list(trt~"{n}/{N} ({p}%)")) %>% 
 
  modify_column_hide(columns = "stat_2") %>%
  
  add_p() %>%
  add_overall()
```

Output:

[image]

Now, if you want to hide parameters of statistical tests you run, you would do it as indicated here:

https://rdrr.io/cran/gtsummary/man/modify_column_hide.html